# Nlog Database logging doesn't insert row

Tags: c#, nlog

I am learning NLog and have moved on to Database logging. I have tried multiple examples on the web and can't get any of them to actually insert a record. I can't see why the log attempt failed due to NLog gobbling up any exceptions it gets. My logger and the config is found without issue. It executes the line as if it worked but the table remains empty. I did step for step on Nlog's example but it doesn't work either! :(
[Nlog Database Example](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target)

UPDATE: I ended up deleting and starting over on the config and it now works. Not sure what fixed the issue from the new config file but i also realized the asp renders were causing errors so i removed them.

```xml
<target name="db"
    xsi:type="Database"
    dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    commandType="StoredProcedure"
    commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]">
    <parameter name="@machineName"    layout="${machinename}" />
    <parameter name="@siteName"       layout="${iis-site-name}" />
    <parameter name="@logged"         layout="${date}" />
    <parameter name="@level"          layout="${level}" />
    <parameter name="@username"       layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
    <parameter name="@message"        layout="${message}" />
    <parameter name="@logger"         layout="${logger}" />
    <parameter name="@properties"     layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
    <parameter name="@serverName"     layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />
    <parameter name="@port"           layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />
    <parameter name="@url"            layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}" />
    <parameter name="@https"          layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}" />
    <parameter name="@serverAddress"  layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />
    <parameter name="@remoteAddress"  layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}" />
    <parameter name="@callSite"       layout="${callsite}" />
    <parameter name="@exception"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
</target>
```

```cs
try
{
    int zero = 0;
    int result = 100 / zero;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger filelogger = LogManager.GetLogger("filelogger");
    Logger dblogger = LogManager.GetLogger("dblogger");
    //filelogger.Error(ex, "Whoops");
    dblogger.Error(ex, "Whoops");
}
```

Comment: Update i got the internal logging to work and now i am seeing the errors Nlog is throwing. It is coming back with an Unknown Log Level: true error. The web seems very limited about this error for nlog and i have gone over the config multiple times and can't see the issue. I am beginning to wonder if this is a bug in Nlog.

Comment: `true` isn't a log level.  It should be something like debug, info, error etc. So probably you had in your config `true` while a log level was expected.

Comment: That is correct, it was one of the issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with asp layout renders and missing a package for them. Also i had set the internalLogging flag to an invalid value. These corrections fixed the problem.